# Rspec: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have seen some examples of this error, and tried a lot of things but none of them work for me.

Test in Rspec:

```
 it "should load data of invoices" do
     post :Invoices , taxiNo: "T2"                     
     expect(response.status).to eq(201) 
 end
```

Routes:

```
 post "/Invoices",   :to => "taxidriver#getInvoices"
```

Controller:

```
class TaxidriverController < ApplicationController

    def getInvoices
        render :text => {:message => "A new Taxi created"}.to_json, :status => :created 
    end
end
```

I am not sure about the line     `post :Invoices , taxiNo: "T2"` 
Should I hit the url ? or should I hit the method?

I also tried `post :getInvoices, taxiNo: "T2"`  but still the same error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
     No route matches {:action=>"Invoices", :controller=>"bookings", :taxiNo=>"T2"}
     # ./spec/controllers/bookings_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I assume you should be able to get an error message like
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches 
`{:action=>"someaction", :controller=>"yourcontroller"} `
could you post the whole error message?

Comment: @NorlyCanarias i have updated my question

Comment: You should be passing the action name getInvoices and not the route
see 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e2fcb2b4aec69e10a01cebfe51bbd280ce6d5a93/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L519

, how about the complete error when you tried the other one? `post :getInvoices, taxiNo: "T2"`.

Comment: I was checking wrong controller, thx

Comment: FYI, in Ruby world, people prefer snake_case rather than camelCase. So you should rename your method to `get_invoices` and do `post :get_invoices, taxiNo: 'T2'`

Answer (score 3):

The specific error your currently getting about "no route matches" is because you wrote your spec like this ...

```
post :Invoices , taxiNo: "T2"
```

When according to your routes and controller you named the method "getInvoices"

So you need to change your spec to this

```
post :getInvoices , taxiNo: "T2"
```

Comment: right. `rspec` looks for an `action method` not a `route`.